# What is the equivalent form of full outer join in relational algebra?

Tags: database-theory, databases, relational-algebra

Considering only basic relational algebra operations, how can we implement the full outer-join ?

Comment: A simple google search yields [this](https://info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_16_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035-1146-160K/aqq1472240815643.html)

Comment: @Sagnik well, I need to ignore any type of join and only consider basic operations (the solution comes with inner join).

Answer (score 1):

Full outer join returns null in the columns of rows from one table that don't match the other table -- that's a description of SQL.

Standard Relational Algebra doesn't have nulls. [Here explains what would be the consequences](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Outer_joins).

Short answer: 'we' don't want to implement outer joins. If you think you do, think some more until you see why it leads to incoherence of queries.